Do free submodules of a free module with infinite rank always have less rank?
Question:

If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, and $F$ is a left free $R$-module, $N$ is a free submodule of $F$, then do we have $\text{rank }F\ge \text{rank }N$?
(when the rank is infinite we view them as cardinality). (In particular what if $F$ has infinite rank)?

Remark: The case where $\text{rank }F$ is finite is handled in this post.
It states the if $\text{rank }F$ is finite with $N$ a free submodule, then $N$ is necessarily of finite rank and its rank is less than the rank of $F$.
(If $N$ is of infinite rank we can select $(\text{rank }F)+1$ linear independent elements, a contradiction).
But I did not find any post talking about what if $\text{rank }F$ is infinite.
By the way this post discusses the case $R$ is non-commutative.

Appears to be true even for infinite ranks, according to https://mathoverflow.net/a/30866/18205
